# Java/Tomcat: ServletContext & getResourceAsStream Problems

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-inf

I am trying to access a conf file (located in the WEB-INF folder) from a Tomcat web app. At the moment, I have the location of the file hard coded as a `String`. However, this does not work when the tomcat/webapps folder is in a different location than my hard coded `String` indicates. I've looked online and it seems like using the `getResourceAsStream ()` method is what I'm looking for, but I'm having a hard time getting it to work. My application is not liking it when I call the `getServletContext ()` method. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: The relevant block of code

```
BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (getServletContext ().getResourceAsStream ("/WEB-INF/conf.txt")));
```

Comment: 1.) Not liking =? what error. 2.) How does your code look like?

Comment: And the compiler says...

Comment: We really can't help you if you don't post the code

Comment: `BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (getServletContext ().getResourceAsStream ("/WEB-INF/conf.txt")));` >> "The method getServletContext() is undefined for the type ..."

Comment: Still having a really hard time w/ this. I think part of the problem is that I am trying to access this information from a POJO running on a Tomcat servlet. Can I get the servletContext from an MBean running on my Tomcat servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem I created two folders under WEB-INF (path/to/app/WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/) and then put my files in this folder. Then, from my POJO I called `this.getClass.getResourceAsStream ("<filename>")` to open up a stream. To just get a String that was the complete absolute path name of a file I did `this.getClass.getResource ("<filename>").toString ().substring (5)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to load a file from the WEB-INF directory in Tomcat, use the following code:

For example, for a file in WEB-INF/config/config.xml

```
ServletContext context = ....//get servlet context
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config/config.xml");
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how to go about getting the servlet context? I think that is the crux of my problem.

Comment: Furthermore, Eclipse (the IDE I'm using) doesn't even recognize Objects of the type ServletContext.

`ServletContext thisContext;` >> "ServletContext cannot be resolved to a type" with suggestions that seem suitable.

Comment: Make sure your class is extending GenericServlet (e.g. HttpServlet) so you have the `getServletContext()` method available. Also make sure the Apache Tomcat library is in your project's build path in Eclipse; if not, right click your project -> Build Path -> Add Library -> Server Runtime -> Apache Tomcat.

Comment: request.getServletContext, sir

Answer (score 0):

If your config file is at /WEB-INF/config.xml, you could access it from a servlet by using "../config.xml" instead of a full path. This works because compiled application classes are normally located within /WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was really hoping this would work as it is the simplest solution, but it resulted in the following error, "java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../config.txt (No such file or directory)"

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me. I kept my `config` file under `WEB-INF/`

web.xml code snippet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>wizardcontroller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sg.poc.wizard.controller.CustomerWizardController</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>plm-config</param-name>
        <param-value>plm-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Servlet code snippet:

```
String configfile = config.getInitParameter("plm-config") ;
InputStream is = config.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/"+configfile);
System.out.println("Resource Stream is : "+is);
```