# Read the file from WebContent/IMAGES/ instead of WEB-INF

Tags: servlets

I have the following structure in a Java Web Application:

```
TheProject
  -- [WebContent]
  -- -- [WEB-INF]
    -- -- index.jsp
  -- -- [IMAGES]
  -- -- -- image.jpg
  -- [Source Packages]
  ----ImageHandlerServlet.java
```

In ImageHandlerServlet.java, I am using the following code

```
    String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/Images");
```

Which gives following path. D:\BH\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\proj\Images

```
    URL path2 =getServletContext().getResource("/image.jpg");
```

which returns null.

```
    InputStream stream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/image.jpg");
```

which returns null;

I want to read the file from WebContent/IMAGES/ instead of WEB-INF. Using real path it can be achieved. What should I do? I consulted following related posts.

1. [getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797162/getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null)
2. [access-file-inside-webcontent-from-servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415413/access-file-inside-webcontent-from-servlet)
3. [java-tomcat-servletcontext-getresourceasstream-problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081578/java-tomcat-servletcontext-getresourceasstream-problems)

Comment: Keep the images folder outside WEB_INF. WEB-INF blocks the direct access of any resource under it.

Comment: Is it not possible to access the image.jpg from WebContent/Images folder?

Comment: You need to have a predefined location anyway. Apart from a few static images, why do you store images into `WebContent`? It is not the right location to upload images, if you are dynamically uploading images into that location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ServletContext#getResource()` and `getResourceAsStream()` take a path relative to web content. From that point on, you've the image actually in `/IMAGES/image.jpg`.

```
InputStream stream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/IMAGES/image.jpg");
```

Noted should be that you should **never** use `getRealPath()` nor `File` API on webcontent resources.

Also noted should be that using a servlet is unnecessary when you intend to serve out images. When putting outside the private `/WEB-INF` folder, they're this way just publicly accessible as below in JSP:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/IMAGES/image.jpg" />
```

Or in Facelets:

```
<img src="#{request.contextPath}/IMAGES/image.jpg" />
```

Or with JSF:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/IMAGES/image.jpg" />
```

#### See also:

- [What does servletcontext.getRealPath("/") mean and when should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-servletcontext-getrealpath-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it/)